# Моя система грузится медленно Arch linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, boot

Недавно я купил SSD и установил на него arch linux с графической оболочкой xfce.
Все было отлично, система грузилась меньше 10 секунд. Но чрез какое-то время она начала грузится больше 40с. То есть грузится как обычно, показывает логи но после последней строки зависает на секунд 20-30, при этом не подавая никаких признаков жизни. И что удивительно, так это то, что если во время загрузки системы нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> система грузится даже быстрее чем изначально раз, и никаких отличий **внутри** я не замечаю. Я решил узнать за сколько же все таки грузится моя система, и вот что вышло:

```
~ ❯❯❯ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 3.418s (kernel) + 2.178s (userspace) = 5.596s
graphical.target reached after 1.998s in userspace
```

Что это значит? И как же всё таки ускорить загрузку?

Comment: Обновите систему до последних версий всего. Почитайте, что написано в журналах событий.